# Error while using sqlalchemy for mysql : Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use sqlalchemy to connect to mysql server configured locally on my laptop.
However I am getting the error :

```
(database) ✔ ~/dev/database [master L|…9] 
13:07 $ python database.py 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
(database) ✘-SEGV ~/dev/database [master L|…9] 

(database) ✘-SEGV ~/dev/database [master L|…9] 
13:07 $ python --version
Python 3.6.9
(database) ✔ ~/dev/database [master L|…9] 
13:22 $ pip freeze
mysql-connector-python==8.0.20
mysqlclient==1.4.6
pkg-resources==0.0.0
protobuf==3.12.2
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.17
(database) ✔ ~/dev/database [master L|…9]
```

Code :

```
#!/bin/python3

"""
    Python module to interact with database.
"""
import sqlalchemy as db


class DataBase:

    def __init__(self, db_url):
        self.engine = db.create_engine(db_url)
        self.metadata = db.MetaData(self.engine)

        self.inventory = db.Table(
            'inventory',
            self.metadata,
            db.Column('address', db.String, primary_key=True),
            db.Column('name', db.String),
            db.Column('device_type', db.String, default='cisco_ios'),
            db.Column('group', db.String, nullable=False),
        )

        self.connect()
        self.metadata.create_all()
        self.disconnect()

    def connect(self):
        self.conn = self.engine.connect()
        if self.conn.closed:
            raise OSError("Tried to connect to DB server but connection still closed.")

    def disconnect(self):
        self.conn.close()

    def insert(self):
        pass

    def select(self):
        pass

    def update(self):
        pass

    def delete(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = DataBase("mysql+mysqlconnector://root:mysql@localhost:3306/inventory_db")
```

Initial troubleshooting shows that whenever I am using "metadata" it is causing this error.
I if comment out "self.metadata.create_all()" and "self.metadata = db.MetaData(self.engine)" I do not get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Found what the problem was, There is something wrong with mysql-python-connector, things do not work as expected if you use that. I used mysqlclient and it worked.